# error installing RDoc documentation: incompatible encoding regexp match

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding, rubygems, rdoc

Over the last week, on a few gem install or gem update operations, I've received an error similar to these:

```
ERROR:  While generating documentation for sinatra-1.3.1 ... MESSAGE:   error generating C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/doc/sinatra-1.3.1/rdoc/README_de_rdoc.html: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with IBM437 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

similarly:

```
ERROR:  While generating documentation for rest-client-1.6.7 ... MESSAGE:   error generating C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/doc/rest-client-1.6.7/rdoc/README_rdoc.html: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with IBM437 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

and possibly one other place. I've read up on this but don't find a solution for code I did not write and data I don't control. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

michael.rp almost had it, but no quotes on the environment string for Windows. The same solution for Linux appears in the link supplied by jerry. For Windows:

`set RDOCOPT=--encoding=UTF-8`

I put this in the `RubyInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\setup_environment.bat` file so it is always there.

Comment: I don't have such file (setup_environment.bat). Can you help me?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu and updating rubygems itself solved the problem for me. You can do that by entering the following at the command line:

```
gem update --system
```

Also, you can always skip the doc generation by using:

```
--no-rdoc --no-ri
```

when installing the gem.

Comment: This did work for me. 

Another solution, which I did not try, was offered here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3743#issuecomment-3340507

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, [this](http://tinkeringruby.blogspot.com/2012/01/heroku-installation.html) worked for me:

```
> set RDOCOPT="--encoding=UTF-8"
> gem install heroku
```

Comment: You solution still failed on an update to Sinatra--until I removed the quotes from the environment string. I had to uninstall and reinstall Sinatra to get the RDoc install to be reattempted, but it then worked.