# jekyll regeneration failed with unicode posts

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I try to regerate my **jekyll** blog with **unicode** post (**russian** text with **utf-8** encoding) and cannot to do it because of:

```
D:\Dropbox\projects\blog>jekyll
Configuration from D:/Dropbox/projects/blog/_config.yml
Building site: . -> ./_site
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/text.rb:131:in `=~': incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with IBM437 string) (Encoding::Compati
bilityError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/text.rb:131:in `!~'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/text.rb:131:in `check'
    …
```

[***Full error log on pastebin***](http://pastebin.com/zLRc5Bt5)

My _config.yml: ***[(full config on pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/C7zTQ1zp)***

```
safe:        false
auto:        false
server:      false
server_port: 4000
baseurl:    /
…
```

I checked **[[error installing RDoc …]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897101/error-installing-rdoc-documentation-incompatible-encoding-regexp-match)** and **[[heroku installation problems]](http://tinkeringruby.blogspot.com/2012/01/heroku-installation.html)** and solutions was not helpful for me.

I will provide any addition information to solve this problem

Comment: Can you post your _config.yml ? Thanks.

Comment: @motleydev I added note about unicode symbols and _config.yml.

Comment: I've had finicky problems in the past with blank returns in my front matter - have you tried pulling those out?

Comment: @motleydev If I replace my russian posts with english ones, jekyll regeretion works as well.

Comment: Hmmm... then sadly I must back out of the "suggestion ring" - I hope you get this resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`chcp 65001`**](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/201#issuecomment-3758617) in cmd helps me everytime before running jekyll. But I think it is not full solution

Answer (score 5):

**`chcp 65001`** did not work on my system, then jekyll returns immediately.

A simple way to work around this error is to avoid non ASCII characters in file names of the posts and pages. The file content itself can be UTF-8 without problem, if it does not start with a BOM.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following fix: https://github.com/bradleywright/jekyll/commit/576f97e2610ef3259a3ea778537d244bc438da20

It worked for me. It is just a change in a line so that it forces files to be read in utf-8